# How to prevent BASH_REMATCH leaking out of a function?

Tags: bash, memory-leaks

I would like to use the bash operator `+~` to first split a string and then check the resulting strings again. When I tried this if found that the elements of `BASH_REMATCH` are overwritten by the second usage, so the mother-function fails on the second use.

Take for example the following constructed example:

```
#!/bin/bash

inputline="abc123ABC123abc,xyz890XYZ890xyz"

checkABC ()
{
    local teststring="$1"
    local pattern="([^,]+),(.*)"

    if [[ $teststring =~ $pattern ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        checkNum ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        checkNum ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    fi

}

checkNum ()
{
    if [[ $1 =~ [a-z]+([0-9]+)[A-Z]+([0-9]+)[a-z]+ ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
}

set -x
checkABC $inputline
```

This will give the following output and we can see, how `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` is overwritten by the function `checkNum`.

```
$ bash ./leaking.sh
+ checkABC abc123ABC123abc,xyz890XYZ890xyz
+ local teststring=abc123ABC123abc,xyz890XYZ890xyz
+ local 'pattern=([^,]+),(.*)'
+ [[ abc123ABC123abc,xyz890XYZ890xyz =~ ([^,]+),(.*) ]]
+ echo 'abc123ABC123abc; xyz890XYZ890xyz'
abc123ABC123abc; xyz890XYZ890xyz
+ checkNum abc123ABC123abc
+ [[ abc123ABC123abc =~ [a-z]+([0-9]+)[A-Z]+([0-9]+)[a-z]+ ]]
+ echo '123; 123'
123; 123
+ checkNum 123
+ [[ 123 =~ [a-z]+([0-9]+)[A-Z]+([0-9]+)[a-z]+ ]]
```

I know that I can prevent that by copying the results of the rematch to another array, which I can treat locally and apply `checkNum` on (see example below). Is this the intelligent way to do it, or **is there a better way to prevent `BASH_REMATCH` from leaking out of the function?**

This code

```
#!/bin/bash

inputline="abc123ABC123abc,xyz890XYZ890xyz"

checkABC ()
{
    local teststring="$1"
    local pattern="([^,]+),(.*)"
    local -a storeRematch

    if [[ $teststring =~ $pattern ]]; then
        storeRematch=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]}")
        echo "${storeRematch[1]}; ${storeRematch[2]}"
        checkNum ${storeRematch[1]}
        checkNum ${storeRematch[2]}
    fi

}

checkNum ()
{
    if [[ $1 =~ [a-z]+([0-9]+)[A-Z]+([0-9]+)[a-z]+ ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
}

set -x
checkABC $inputline
```

executes like I want it to:

```
bash ./notleaking.sh
+ checkABC abc123ABC123abc,xyz890XYZ890xyz
+ local teststring=abc123ABC123abc,xyz890XYZ890xyz
+ local 'pattern=([^,]+),(.*)'
+ local -a storeRematch
+ [[ abc123ABC123abc,xyz890XYZ890xyz =~ ([^,]+),(.*) ]]
+ storeRematch=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]}")
+ echo 'abc123ABC123abc; xyz890XYZ890xyz'
abc123ABC123abc; xyz890XYZ890xyz
+ checkNum abc123ABC123abc
+ [[ abc123ABC123abc =~ [a-z]+([0-9]+)[A-Z]+([0-9]+)[a-z]+ ]]
+ echo '123; 123'
123; 123
+ checkNum xyz890XYZ890xyz
+ [[ xyz890XYZ890xyz =~ [a-z]+([0-9]+)[A-Z]+([0-9]+)[a-z]+ ]]
+ echo '890; 890'
890; 890
```

Comment: @andlrc I tried `local -a BASH_REMATCH` already (forgot to include that) and it completely breaks the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a hack but as it is only local to the current shell you can run a subshell in the function.

```
checkNum ()
{
(
    if [[ $1 =~ [a-z]+([0-9]+)[A-Z]+([0-9]+)[a-z]+ ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
)
}
```

or

```
(
 checkNum ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
 checkNum ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
)
```

This will keep the BASH_REMATCH from being global to both functions.

Other than that i think Assigning it to another array is the best you are going to get(better than this infact as it doesn't open a new process/subshell).

Answer (score 1):

`BASH_REMATCH` is a readonly variable, so things like `local BASH_REMATCH` would *not* work.

Alternative as you suggest yourself you can copy the result to another variable:

```
local re
re=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]}")
```

And in your case - just to mention it - you can use:

```
# teststring="1234,5678"
checkNum "${teststring%%,*}" # 1234
checkNum "${teststring#*,}"  # 5678
```